# Rsync error in task scheduler

Tags: command-line, batch, rsync, cron

I need to run a cron with rsync. 
I wrote a batch script, That is my script:

```
START C:\cygwin64\bin\rsync.exe -v -rlt -z -p --update --delete  --progress --log-file=/home/Administrator/rsynclogs/Invoices.log  "/cygdrive/y/folderA//" "/cygdrive/e/folderB//"
```

When I run the script from command prompt, a new command prompt gets open and the script get's executed correctly. When I run it from task scheduler I get this error:

```
2019/03/11 10:40:07 [6000] building file list
2019/03/11 10:40:07 [6000] rsync: change_dir "/cygdrive/y/folderA/" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2019/03/11 10:40:07 [6000] sent 20 bytes  received 12 bytes  64.00 bytes/sec
2019/03/11 10:40:07 [6000] total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
2019/03/11 10:40:07 [6000] rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

What can be the problem? 
Please don't tell me to install cron with cygwin, at this point I want to try and fix it without it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `rsync` together with `bash` in order to have access to `/path/to/somewhere` type of files. In CMD, you can only use paths like `C:\to\somewhere` etc.

So to solve the problem, you can try this in your script:

```
start C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c '/bin/rsync.exe ...'
```

A simple test:

[image]

Comment: The commend doesn't pass trough. Tried from cmd as well.

Comment: @matisa It should work. Please check screenshot I added to answer.

Comment: Ok, not work in bash - still the  same error. 
In bout cases I get the error only when I run it from task scheduler.